# In protobuf-net can i have a byte field?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

In protobuf-net can i have a byte field? Is a byte array field part of the protocol buffers spec?

Basically I want to transmit various objects over the wire. In this case the byte[] Payload will be another protocol buffer serialised object. I do this so i don't need to specificy type

thanks

```
public sealed class CellUpdateTransmission
{
    public int RowIndex { get; private set; }
    public int CellIndex { get; private set; }          
    public byte[] Payload {get;private set;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can.  In your second phase, move the bytes into a memory stream and then deserialize as per normal.

```
            byte[] Payload= datafromsomewhere;
            var ms = new MemoryStream(Payload);
            var req = Serializer.Deserialize<AbcClass>(ms);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both `byte` and `byte[]` are supported; the latter maps to `bytes` in the .proto spec. This is actually the same as how a sub-message is normally represented anyway. Just let the serializer know about the member (most simply: by adding an attribute such as `[ProtoMember(3)]`).

Comment: Does the byte field map to anything in the .proto spec? Or will I need to find a different way to deserialize binary data written with byte fields? Thanks!

Comment: @Toolbox one byte? or many bytes? varint (used for int/uint) would take 1 byte for 0-127 and 2 bytes for 128-255; `bytes` maps to multiple bytes cleanly.